# iOS rendering input button incorrectly

Tags: ios, css

So I made a search bar, and everything works fine. Except the css.

This is what it looks like on computers:

[Search bar on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zjrH.png)

And this is what it looks like on iOS: (tested on iPhone, iPad, and iPod)

[Search bar on iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjkdk.png)

You'll notice that on the iPad, the search text height is greater than the button.

This is my css:

```
input.searchFormText {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 2.25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4.25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4.25px;
  height: 19.5px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 12.25px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  transition-duration: 0.225s;
}
```

So I need the search text input height to be less, but only on iOS.

Comment: It appears fine on Android too.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason iOS Safari gives the input element a different default padding than other browsers. Just set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of your input and it should have the same height in every browser ;)